# web site publish shows index of/

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, web-applications

I've published a web site using VS 2010 by the publish web option to an ftp site.
It shows that the publish was succeeded but when I go the site I see "Index of/" and not the site itself.
The default page to run is default.aspx and its all with lower cases as I saw few suggestions about this issue.

What can be the problem?

Comment: Could you please post what did you see when went to the site? I mean, the screen shot

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have directory browsing turned on in IIS please see these search results on google - depending on which version of IIS you have you will need to find find the "Disable Directory Browsing" option

https://www.google.co.uk/webhp?rlz=1C1DVCL_enGB455GB455&sourceid=chrome-instant&ie=UTF-8&ion=1#hl=en&rlz=1C1DVCL_enGB455GB455&sclient=psy-ab&q=turn+off+directory+browsing+IIS&oq=turn+off+directory+browsing+IIS&gs_l=hp.3..0j0i30l3.3079.14321.0.14701.40.17.9.10.10.1.231.2502.3j10j4.17.0...0.0...1c.BCb_w6c0oBI&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=99b0cee94ed2fe06&ion=1&biw=1527&bih=871